# My global variable is not changing (Python)

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets, server, global-variables

I am making an online flag guessing game using sockets.
Server's code below (sorry for pasting the entire code, I've been testing and have literally no idea what the problem could be):

```
import socket
import threading
import random
from time import sleep
from func import get_flags


flags = get_flags()
flag_names = [i for i in flags]
current_flag = " "
show_answer = False

errorCounter = 0

HEADER = 64
PORT = 5050
SERVER = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
ADDR = (SERVER, PORT)
FORMAT = 'utf-8'

server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server.bind(ADDR)

players = []
num_of_players = int(input("Number of players: "))

def handle_client(conn, addr):
    global show_answer, current_flag

    print(f"[NEW CONNECTION] {addr} connected.")

    connected = True
    player = ()
    while connected:
        print(current_flag)

        msg_length = conn.recv(HEADER).decode(FORMAT)
        if msg_length:
            msg_length = int(msg_length)
            msg = conn.recv(msg_length).decode(FORMAT)
            #print(f"[{addr}] {msg}")

            msg = msg.lower()
            msg = msg.split(" ")
            try:
                if msg[0] == "!set_username" and len(msg) > 1:
                    player = (msg[1], addr)
                    players.append(player)

                elif msg[0] == "!get_flags":
                    conn.send(str(flags).encode(FORMAT))

                elif msg[0] == "!ready":
                    conn.send(str(len(players) >= num_of_players).encode(FORMAT))

                elif msg[0] == "!get_current_flag":
                    conn.send(current_flag.encode(FORMAT))

                elif msg[0] == "!show_answer":
                    conn.send(str(show_answer).encode(FORMAT))
                    
            except Exception:
                print("asd")

            #conn.send("Msg received".encode(FORMAT))
    players.remove(player)
    conn.close()


def start():
    global show_answer, current_flag

    server.listen()
    print(f"[LISTENING] Server is listening on {SERVER}:{PORT}")
    while len(players) < num_of_players:
        conn, addr = server.accept()
        thread = threading.Thread(target=handle_client, args=(conn, addr))
        thread.start()

    print("\nThe game has started.\n")
    while True:
        sleep(3)
        show_answer = False
        current_flag = random.choice(flag_names)
        sleep(10)
        show_answer = True


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("[STARTING] server is starting...")
    start()
```

My problem is:
When I call the start() function, and the lobby fills up, the "game clock" starts, which determines how much time the players have to guess the flag, and the time in which they can see the correct answer. When I change these variables (show_answer and current_flag), they change, but not in in handle_client(). Why is that?

The client is able to connect just fine, but can't see the updated variables.
I am using Python 3.9.5 if that helps.

Comment: There is a typo in `handle_client`: `show_awnser` ...

Comment: yeah I realized that awnser was not the correct way to spell answer while posting this so I quickly changed the variable names and left that out, so the typo was created while posting lol

Comment: `global` variables are usually recommended against, as they can cause a variety of problms. You might want to consider another approach, such as a class with instance variables, for your code.